# Only, Uncover and Visible Beamer overlay commands within a minted codeblock

Tags: beamer, minted, overlays

I want to explain a complicated piece of LaTeX code in a presentation by using beamer's overlays within a minted codeblock. Existing solutions I found are not sufficient because of two main issues:

1. I need to uncover the code non-linearly, thus simple `\pause`s won't be enough
2. I don't want the code to be revealed line by line, but sometimes also only parts of a line, thus I cannot split the code block into multiple different minted blocks

For simplicity, this is something like the complicated code that I want to explain (the real block is a bit longer):

```latex
Let \(x,y \in \mathbb{R}\).
\begin{align*}
    x + y &= y + x\\
        &= x + y
\end{align*}
```

And this is the way I want the code to be revealed:

```latex
Let \(x,y \in \mathbb{R}\).
\uncover<2->{\begin{align*}}
    \uncover<3->{x + y} \uncover<4->{&= y + x\\}
        \uncover<5->{&= x + y}
\uncover<2->{\end{align*}}
```

(note that this code itself won't actually compile, but I want to demonstrate the order in which I want the verbatim code to be shown)

I have tried the following things:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{minted}
\setminted{autogobble=true}

\begin{document}

% approach 1
\begin{frame}[fragile]{\LaTeX{} Example}
    \begin{minted}[escapeinside=||,beameroverlays=true]{latex}
        Let \(x,y \in \mathbb{R}\).
        |\uncover<2->{|\begin{align*}|}|
            |\uncover<3->{|x + y|}| |\uncover<4->{|&= y + x\\|}|
                |\uncover<5->{|&= x + y|}|
        |\uncover<2->|\end{align*}|}|
    \end{minted}
\end{frame}

% approach 2
\begin{frame}[fragile]{\LaTeX{} Example}
    \begin{minted}[escapeinside=||,beameroverlays=true]{latex}
        Let \(x,y \in \mathbb{R}\).
        |\uncover<2->{\begin{align*}}|
            |\uncover<3->{x + y}| |\uncover<4->{&= y + x\\}|
                |\uncover<5->{&= x + y}|
        |\uncover<2->{\end{align*}}|
    \end{minted}
\end{frame}

% approach 3
% same as appraoch 2, but this time with \mintinline inside the escaped blocks
\begin{frame}[fragile]{\LaTeX{} Example}
    \begin{minted}[escapeinside=||,beameroverlays=true]{latex}
        Let \(x,y \in \mathbb{R}\).
        |\uncover<2->{\mintinline{latex}{\begin{align*}}}|
            |\uncover<3->{\mintinline{latex}{x + y}}| |\uncover<4->{\mintinline{latex}{&= y + x\\}}|
                |\uncover<5->{\mintinline{latex}{&= x + y}}|
        |\uncover<2->{\mintinline{latex}{\end{align*}}}|
    \end{minted}
\end{frame}

% appraoch 4
\begin{frame}[fragile]{\LaTeX{} Example}
    \begin{minted}[escapeinside=||,beameroverlays=true]{latex}
        Let \(x,y \in \mathbb{R}\).
        |\onslide<2->|\begin{align*}
            |\onslide<3->|x + y |\onslide<4->|&= y + x\\
                |\onslide<5->|&= x + y
        |\onslide<2->|\end{align*}
    \end{minted}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Approach 1 and 2 compile, but with errors and without the desired result. Approach 3 does not compile at all. Approach 4 compiles with the desired result.

Clearly Approach 4 works, however I find it rather ugly. Using `\onslide` in the variant with no text given will cause problems for everything that comes after the codeblock. For example, when `\onslide<2->` is put into a `tcolorbox` environment, for some reason beamer's footline will go invisible for the first slide (note that this can be fixed by inserting `\onslide<1->` after the minted block). Additionally, while `\onslide` can be switched to the equivalent of a `\visible` command by using `\onslide+`, it cannot be switched to the equivalent of `\only`. I don't require an `\only` command in this case, but if I did, approach 4 would not work.

Approach 1 presumably doesn't work because the escaped blocks are all treated separately. Approach 2 would never give the desired result anyway as everything within the escaped blocks will be rendered as normal LaTeX, not as verbatim. Thus I tried wrapping those into a `\mintinline` command with approach 3, but why that doesn't compile is an absolute mystery to me. I don't understand LaTeX's error messages with approach 3 frankly. I assume that, even if approach 3 were to compile, it would still cause issues, as each escaped part would be seen as its own LaTeX code, which might mess up context-dependent highlighting.

Is approach 4 the *only* way to achieve what I want? And what would I have to do if I actually wanted an `\only` command? Obviously you could always just copy the whole codeblock however many times you need and use `onlyenv`, but that is quite a dirty solution (and actually causes inconsistent sizing of the code blocks). Is there any other way to use `\uncover` (as well as `\only` and `\visible`) from within a minted code block?

Comment: Are the bits that should be `\uncover`ed always whole lines?

Comment: wow, reading is not my forte: "2. I don't want the code to be revealed line by line"... I'll reconsider my approach (which I absolutely not started to code, it was only existing in my head)

Comment: You can't escape the start and end of an argument separately. I would use `\onslide` and its variants for your use case.

Comment: Different approach: you could use the tikzmarks library to mark the start and end of the elements in your code and then cover up the pieces with rectangles in the the background colour on the appropriate overlays.

Answer (score 0):

You can't escape the start and end of an argument separately. I would use `\onslide` and its variants for your use case.

As an alternative, you could use the tikzmarks library to mark the start and end of the elements in your code and then cover up the pieces with rectangles in the the background colour on the appropriate overlays.

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}

\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{minted}
\setminted{autogobble=true}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{\LaTeX{} Example}
    \begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{latex}
        LLet \(x,y \in \mathbb{R}\).
        |\tikzmark{bar}|\begin{align*}|\tikzmark{foo}|
    \end{minted}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill<-2>[bg] ([yshift=-1ex]pic cs:bar) rectangle ([yshift=2ex]pic cs:foo);
\fill<3-4>[bg,opacity=0.85] ([yshift=-1ex]pic cs:bar) rectangle ([yshift=2ex]pic cs:foo);
\end{tikzpicture}   

\pause[5]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]